# Javascript IF screen width then hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, show-hide, nav

Trying to get a result whereby if the window size is less that 900px then the items hide themselves on document load. However running into trouble as the code I know works when not in an IF wont work when it is enclosed in an IF statement?

```js
var searchEl = document.querySelector("#input");
if ($(window).width() > 960) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").load(function(){
        $(".mobile-nav-hide").hide();
    });
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".mobile-nav-hide").toggle();

    });
});
}
```

```css
h4.mobile-nav {
    font-family: GillSansMTStd-Medium;
    color: #5F5A51;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h4.mobile-nav:hover {
    background-color: #7BAF8A;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
h4.mobile-nav {
    display: none;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
h4.mobile-nav {
    display: none;
}
}
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 851px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 924px;
}
}

ul.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #E8DDBF /*#E8DFCE*/; 
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
ul.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #E8DDBF /*#E8DFCE*/; 
    height: 35px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
ul.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #E8DDBF /*#E8DFCE*/; 
    height: 40px;
}
}

li.nav {
    width: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
li.nav {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
li.nav {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
}

li.nav a.nav {
    font-family: GillSansMTStd-Medium;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5F5A51;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
li.nav a.nav {
    font-family: GillSansMTStd-Medium;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #5F5A51;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
li.nav a.nav {
    font-family: GillSansMTStd-Medium;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5F5A51;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}




li.nav a.nav:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #7BAF8A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-container">
   
   <nav>
    <h4 class="mobile-nav" button id="toggle">Menu</h4>
    <div class="mobile-nav-hide">
    <ul class="nav" class="search">
     <li class="nav" style="margin-left: 0px;"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT &amp; TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT &amp; TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT &amp; TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT</a></li>
     <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#home">TEXT</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE:** I don't seem to have made it clear that the page needs to hide the li elements under the Menu item, for use in the hide/show, when the width < 900px and then have no effect then the width is over 900px.

Comment: Then the if condition is wrong, not the code block.

Comment: First, your JavaScript is wrong. the first two lines should be.inside "`$(document).ready`. Second, you are already using media queries. In that case, why not just use them for this as well?

Comment: The function works if I use the below js, however when the page > 900px nothing of the navigation is displayed, that is why I am trying to make the hide on load conditional to the page width.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").load(function(){
        $(".mobile-nav-hide").hide();
    });
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".mobile-nav-hide").toggle();

    });
});

Comment: What is the distinction you are making between this being a job for JavaScript and not a CSS Media Query? You can create a media query that says when page width > 960px hide the specific elements. As @caulitomaz mentions in their answer, if you implement this logic in JavaScript: the viewer of the site will have to refresh the page manually if they decide to view the screen at a smaller size where you wish to show the specific elements. The opposite is true of media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should prefer using only media queries for this problem.
There is no need for using javascript here. Besides that, your logic is flawed.

The reason behind this is that:

1. Your will not need to wait for the DOM ready callback to make it work, it will feel faster
2. Your logic fails consider resizing events (If the user starts at 970px width but then resizes to 700px width, what happens?)
3. There is no reason to use logic blocks for something that is merely visual and doable by CSS

#### "But I really want to use javascript!"

Take a look at this approach (not tested). It fixes your non-resizing-checking issue and adds a clean toggling of classes for your desired selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   function checkNeedForHiding() {
      // TODO Use throttling here
      $(".mobile-nav-hide").toggleClass("hidden", function() { return $(window).width() > 960; } ); 
   }

   $( window ).resize(function() {
     checkNeedForHiding();
   });

   checkNeedForHiding();
});
```

Comment: The use for javascript is to show and hide the list of navigation items on the click of the 'menu' button when the browser size is below 900px so that they are not all listed and take up half the page, I have no use for the js when the page size is bigger than 900px, only when it is less.

Comment: Ok, this wasn't clear. But your shouldn't be varying your javascript depending on screen sizes. I still think you should be solving this taking advantage of CSS media queries.

Comment: Not aware of any way to to show and hide elements on click using css, hence the js use. I just want the js to operate when the page is smaller than 900px and then do nothing when its bigger than 900px.

Comment: A clean way to do this is to addClass or removeClass to the desired elements (hence the toogleClass on my answer). The class added/removed will show or hide the DOM element.

Comment: Your code doesn't solve my problem of enabling the hiding of li items when the page is under 900px wide only.

Comment: Of course, you need to implement the '.hidden' class on your CSS, and apply it to all elements you need on the block of code. I am pretty sure this solves your problem.